# ChromeHeadless failed to start stdout / Cannot start ChromeHeadless with PhantomJS / Karma

Tags: google-chrome, browser, karma-runner, headless-browser

I'm currently running tests using PhantomJS and Karma to test a Angular.js application. With the recent release of ChromeHeadless, we have started using ChromeHeadless test browser instead of the default PhantomJS browser.

I currently have [`karma-chrome-launcher`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-chrome-launcher) 2.1.0 installed.

When I run my tests, I am presented with several different errors, extracts of which are listed below:

```
Cannot start ChromeHeadless
    [0510/113948.371837:ERROR:resource_bundle.cc(767)] Failed to load /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/58.0.3029.110/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/A/resources.pak
Some features may not be available.

ChromeHeadless stdout:
10 05 2017 11:39:48.428:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stderr: [0510/113948.371837:ERROR:resource_bundle.cc(767)] Failed to load /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/58.0.3029.110/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/A/resources.pak
Some features may not be available.

ChromeHeadless stderr: [0510/113948.490917:ERROR:resource_bundle.cc(767)] Failed to load /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/58.0.3029.110/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/A/resources.pak
Some features may not be available.

ChromeHeadless failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I have tried running a few npm commands, namely `npm rebuild` and `npm update` as I initially thought it was a dependency issue. That didn't work and I am not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was due to the version of Google Chrome I had installed. Headless Chrome is supported from Chrome 59 onwards, whereas I had 58 installed.

I installed the [Chrome Beta](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html) to gain access to Headless Chrome.

Comment: Chrome 59 is now stable.